# Android: How can I detect Touch Down event on a View & Touch Up event on another view

Tags: android, events, touch, view

I have a parent (Container) view of type ViewGroup that at run-time I add to it unknown number of child views.

At run-time I want to detect which child view received touch down event & which child view received touch up event ( In case I pressed on a child view & moved to another view where I left my finger).

In my code below when I press on a child view & move - without releasing my finger - to another child view and left up my finger, I get the same view I pressed on ( I can't detect the 2nd child view).

```
childView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
      {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), v.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
      {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), v.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
      {

       }

return false;
    }
});
```

Additional Info:

**I'm using my code on Android 4.1.2 (API 16 and forward).**

**I'm listening to Click events too.**

Comment: I don't think Android will do what you're asking. ACTION_UP's can only come from objects that previously saw (and reported) an ACTION_DOWN. View-type objects ignore finger releases that weren't preceded by a finger touch on the same object. Confirmation: If you touch and then slide off a View before releasing, you won't get an ACTION_UP. But if you touch, slide off, slide BACK, and then release you will get an ACTION_UP. The way I've solved this in the past is to sense touch events in the overall parent container, then do the X/Y comparisons in your own code. Ugly, I know.